# Examples of transfinite constructions in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monads, transfinite-induction

The nlab has a page on [transfinite construction of free algebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transfinite+construction+of+free+algebras) on the existence of a free monad for a (pointed) endofunctor (accessible in a locally presentable category). My question is if the existence of

- tensor product $- \otimes B$ with an abelian group
- algebraic closure of a field

and other similar classical constructions in algebra fall in this construction, and if so how to see that.

Comment: The tensor product of two abelian groups does not require a transfinite construction. The algebraic closure of a field does require a transfinite construction but it is not a free algebra construction.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a simple example of free algebra construction?

Comment: Well, first you have to find an example of an endofunctor where the algebras are interesting. For instance there is an endofunctor on the category of abelian groups whose algebras are abelian groups equipped with an (additive) endomorphism. With some thought you see that this is a funny way of talking about $\mathbb{Z} [x]$-modules. Ergo the free algebra construction must give you $(-) \otimes \mathbb{Z} [x]$ – but you already know how to construct that directly without transfinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the example too ^^